# Admob banner not showing but working in logcat?

Tags: android

I wrote a test app to implement the admob banner using xml in the layout file. The first time I ran the application, it worked and I could see the banner. I added a second activity and I was able to switch between activities and I still can see the banner.

The following day I tried running the app again and the banner does not show. I checked the catlog and it tells me the a request for ad was succesfull but no ad was returned because my inventory is empty.

I wanted to know if this would be something normal when you are working on eclipse. Or if the banner would still show even if there are no ads in the inventory.

Thanks,

Richard.

Comment: Once check your layouts. Probably your activity layouts are covering the ad layout. Also, do you see the adView layout in the Graphical layout window?

Comment: Rahul, I think you are right. I found a line in the logcat that said it could not load the view. I tried deleting all the views and leaving the code for google ads but nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this error your code is probably correct (you say it worked before and you didn't change anything). The issue is that AdMob does not always have an ad to return to every request. You can enable the  `Use keyword-targeted ads and Google certified ad networks (GCANs) to improve fill rate.` in AdMob app settings to increase the fill rate.

If you want to be sure your code works as intended you can set the testmode to true, if you get back an ad you can be sure your code is correct.